# Pharo Smalltalk: Reading from TextMorph

Tags: windows, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

In Smalltalk using Pharo, I'm creating an application that reads the user input and does X.

So far I've managed to make a TextMorph that a user could enter a value into,
but I'm unsure of how to read from TextMorphs and then do something with the value.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can simply send `text` to your morph and get it's contents. So you could have a button and when button is pressed you do something with contents:

```
input := TextMorph new.
button :=
   SimpleButtonMorph new
      target: self
      actionSelector: #processTextMorph:;
      arguments: {input};
      yourself.

processTextMorph: aTextMorph
   | contents |
   contents := aTextMorph text.
   "do something with contents"
```

However maybe you want to use a dialog? Because you can do:

```
response := UIManager default request: 'What do you want to do?'.
response ifNotNil: [ "do something with the response" ]
```

And then the execution of `UIManager default request: '…'` will open a dialog with a text input

Comment: Thanks i currently have

Comment: is this in your initialize class? When I'm trying to create the method processTextMorph: TextMorph, I get the error "name already defined"

Comment: @Gdohfg can this be because you already have an instance variable named `contents`?

Comment: `processTextMorph:  Name already defined ->TextMorph 

| contents |
contents := TextMorph text.
"do something"`

Comment: `InputField  := TextMorph new.
InputField contents: 'Please enter a Temp'.
InputField color: Color white.
InputField bounds: (350@320 corner: 150@150). 
self addMorph: InputField .` this is my code for the textmorph

Comment: Right, because you name the parameter of your method `TextMorph` which is already a global variable pointing to the class with the same name. If you follow my example and name the parameter `aTextMorph` everything should be fine. Also pay attention: according to the smalltalk coding conventions you should name instance and temporary variable starting with lowercase, the names starting with upper case are used for global variables

Comment: Say if I was to edit the text of the TextMorph, and then do the Function with my button. How could I return this to the TextMorph? thanks