# Pharo Smalltalk: How to create an input field using TextMorph and then get the data off the input field?

Tags: textbox, smalltalk, pharo

I am completely new to Pharo, Smalltalk. I'm developing a small app that will convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius. Can anyone give me any idea on how to create an input field using TextMorph and display it on a window as shown in the screen shot.  In addition, being able to get the data back from the input field when the button is clicked. The below code is what I have done so far.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTWJ.png)

The class TemperatureMorph

```
 BorderedMorph subclass: #TemperatureMorph
        instanceVariableNames: 'tempInputField counter'
        classVariableNames: ''
        package: 'Assignment'
```

The initialize method: Contains a label, textbox and a button.

```
initialize 
    | headingLabel converterButton|
    super initialize.
    self bounds: (0@0 corner:300@300).
    self color: Color gray.

    headingLabel := StringMorph contents: 'Converter'.
    headingLabel position: 130@20. 
    self addMorph: headingLabel.

    tempInputField := TextMorph new.     
    tempInputField position: 50@50. 
    self addMorph: tempInputField.
```

Thanks

Comment: The fact that the solution lies right in front of you in the screenshot makes me wonder whether you have tried something yourself and have done some research before posting this question.

Comment: @Jayk Yes. I did do research and tried the solution myself that you gave me but unfortunately I could not see the text box due to the background I choose. :(

Comment: oh, okay that is bad luck.

Comment: I think the folks on StackOverflow prefer that you ask a new question rather than amending an existing one (so the answers do not get out-of-date). But now that we are here: your converterBtnPressed method only overwrites the text in the input field. It does not even read the entered text. Have you tried something to implement the temperature conversion and can you show it to us, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already see the necessary code in your screenshot, you only have to replace the construction of a StringMorph with that of a TextMorph. I suggest you take a look at the [Pharo by Example](http://files.pharo.org/books/pharo-by-example/) book. It has a chapter on Morphic, which is the UI framework in Pharo.

```
yourTextMorph := TextMorph new.
yourTextMorph contents: 'initial text'.
ownerMorph addMorph: yourTextMorph.
```

I guess you will also want to read the contents back out of the TextMorph. You can use `yourTextMorph contents` to achieve that. See also [Pharo Smalltalk: Reading from TextMorph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912260/pharo-smalltalk-reading-from-textmorph)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been able to do some work on it and have updated the question. However, I was unable to get the data off the input field even after checking the link you provided. I even tired it that solution myself but It does't seem to work for me.

Comment: can you please give me some directions on how I can get the data off the input field. Thank you

Comment: @BigSmile like I wrote: you can get the text in the TextMorph back with `tempInputField contents`. This will give you an instance of the class Text (which is a formatted string). You will need to convert it to a number for your temperature conversion like this: `inputTemperature := tempInputField contents asNumber.` But I am only guessing what you need. What exactly does not work? Does a debugger pop up because of an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: I have updated my **converterBtnPressed** method. However, the error I get is: Instance of Fraction did not understand #asText when I run the code I provided in this question. But if I change the last line in the **converterBtnPressed** to `tempInputField contents: answer asString.` Then input a number e.g. 34 my asnwer is like (10/9).

Comment: @BigSmile Pharo uses fractions instead of floats when it can to not lose precision. If you need decimal fractions, you could use `answer asFloat`. You could also browse the converting and printing methods of Fraction, Float, and Number to see if any of them better suits your needs (e.g. include a limited number of decimal places).

Answer (score 3):

On a side not, if you're doing UI stuff in Pharo for anything other than learning (It looks like OP /is/ learning, so this probably doesn't apply). You should be looking at either Glamour or Spec. Both of which have really easy text input and control systems.

[Spec](http://files.pharo.org/books-pdfs/spec/2017-01-23-SpecBooklet.pdf)
[Glamour](http://gtoolkit.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I am only learning just the basics.

Comment: It is good to learn the basics, but don't get too involved in them. Its all being ripped and replaced with a thing called Bloc (But I believe the API will remain). You should look at Bloc and Bric to see where all this UI stuff is going in the future.